# How to simplify working with provided dependencies?

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I've seen this problem many times that I work on a java/scala project and there's a provided dependency that is on the classpath of the server (so, there's no need to include it inside the uber jar), but locally I don't have it and I have to constantly comment out the `<scope>provided</scope>` setting in pom.xml to make my project work properly.

Is there a way to simplify this somehow, so that I don't have to constantly comment out the `<scope>provided</scope>` thing?

Comment: If you have to comment out something there is in general a problem without a full example it's hard to say...

Comment: What do you mean by "locally, I don't have it?" I do not know the details but it looks like it would be better to adjust your local testing environment (by adding the required dependencies) than editing the POM.

Comment: just install the missing dependencies locally

Comment: What do you mean by "locally"? If you run tests from your IDE or Maven for instance, provided dependencies will be available, no need to comment the scope.

Comment: Also you mention SBT, maven, which one is it?

Comment: @GaëlJ it is both, both maven and sbt have provided dependencies. And provided dependencies are not available.

Comment: "provided dependencies are not available" *when*? What command are you running at that point?

Comment: And when you say "server", do you mean a servlet container like Tomcat, or a machine you are running on?

Comment: @tgdavies machine that i run on, i develop spark applications. and they're not available when i run tests, for example

Comment: What command are you running at that point? You need to run your tests using maven, so that it can set up your classpath correctly.